# how can we manage multiple conditions in a simple condition using ng-show and ng-hide

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to improve multiple conditions using ng-show and ng-hide using directives, here is my code

**html code**

```
 <my-directive controls="a,b,c"></my-directive>
```

**js code**

```
.directive('myDirective',function(){
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl:"parentHtml.html",
    link:function(scope,elem,attr){
      var options = attr.controls;
      if(options=="a,b,c"){
        scope.showMeAll=true;
      }else if(options=="a"){
        scope.showmeA=true;
      }else if(options=="b"){
        scope.showmeB=true;
      }else if(options=="c"){
        scope.showmeC=true;
      }
    }
  }
}).directive('subDirective',function(){
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    template:"<h2>aapple</h2>",
    link:function(scope,elem,attr){

    }
  }
}).directive('subDirective1',function(){
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    template:"<h2>BBatt</h2>",
    link:function(scope,elem,attr){

    }
  }
}).directive('subDirective2',function(){
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    template:"<h2>CCat</h2>",
    link:function(scope,elem,attr){

    }
  }
});
```

**here is my parentHtml.html code**

```
<div class="row">
  <div ng-show="showMeAll">
    <sub-directive></sub-directive>
    </div>
   <div ng-show="showMeB">
    <sub-directive1></sub-directive1>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="showMeC">
    <sub-directive2></sub-directive2>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is when I give all the three "a,b,c" to the directive attribute then in "parentHtml" all the three div's have to show, if I give only two i.e "a,b" then in parentHtml only two div's have to show i.e "apple" and "bat" and also if give only one string i.e "c" then in parentHtml only "cat" div have to show, in a simple way if what the alphabet I give to the directive attribute thet div have to show. Here is my http://plnkr.co/edit/6gAyAi63Ni4Z7l0DP5qm?p=preview. 
 Please solve my question in a simple way.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Instead of checking if the value of the `controls` attribute is equal to a letter eg: `options=="a"` you should check if it contains that letter `options.indexOf("a") !== -1`.

Comment: This is a working version http://plnkr.co/edit/ERdku20aXECxbP30OlP3?p=preview beside the `if(...)else if(...)...` errors you had some spelling errors as well, you were using `showme...` instead of `showMe...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some spelling errors, instead of `showmeA, showmeB, etc.` it should be `showMeA, showMeB, etc.` `me` with a uppercase `M`.

Beside that, your checks don't make sense, you're using `if..else if` checks which means that the evaluation will stop as soon as a condition is true.

Also, in this case, you should check if the value of the `conditions` attribute contains a letter instead of if it is equal to a letter.

Here is a working version of your directive:

```
directive('myDirective',function(){
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl:"parentHtml.html",
    link:function(scope,elem,attr){
      var options = attr.controls;
      if(options.indexOf("a") !== -1){
        scope.showMeA=true;
      }
      if(options.indexOf("b") !== -1){
        scope.showMeB=true;
      }
      if(options.indexOf("c") !== -1){
        scope.showMeC=true;
      }
      scope.showMeAll = scope.showMeB && scope.showMeA && scope.showMeC;
  }
 }
})
```

and [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/ERdku20aXECxbP30OlP3?p=preview) is a demo

Comment: it is working perfectly but when we give only "a" in controls then it is not showing "apple" remaining all are coming well @Titus

Comment: @Midhunsai That is because, in you're template, you've set "Applet" to be shown when `showMeAll` is set to `true`, you'll need to change that so it will show "Apple" when `showMeA` is `true` or change the directive to set `showMeAll` to true when only `a` is selected

Answer (score 3):

All your divs that wrap directives have ng-show, so the code should be :

```
if(options=="a,b,c"){
    scope.showMeAll=true;
    scope.showMeA=true;
    scope.showMeB=true;
    scope.showMeC=true;
 }
```

By setting ng-show to true to the parnet div,  wont display other child divs that have ng-show. Child divs have independent ng-show from parent.